# Facebook fetching incorrect OG tags for NextJS project deployed on Vercel

Tags: facebook-graph-api, next.js, facebook-opengraph, server-side-rendering, vercel

I have built my project using NextJS and deployed it on Vercel. My project's Vercel URL is `https://my-project.vercel.app`. My domain (added to project settings in Vercel dashboard) is `www.example.com`

When I use [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to inspect the meta tags on a particular url, the meta tags are picked up correctly when using the `my-project.vercel.app` domain and not my actual domain `www.example.com`. The project loads correctly in the browser , including meta tags, for both domains.

For example, for a url `/foo` on my website, the og tags are picked up correctly for `https://my-project.vercel.app/foo` but not for `https://www.example.com/foo`.

Have a look at these screenshots. Note that the domain shown in the screenshots (esourcing.in) is added to the project `esourcing-frontend.vercel.app`, in the Vercel dashboard.

[image: Screenshot 2020-10-24 at 4 14 48 PM]

[image: Screenshot 2020-10-24 at 4 16 24 PM]

Here is the screenshot from my browser:

[image]

Comment: The canonical URL is different between the two, for the first one it is set to the same URL, for the second one it appears set to the _base_ URL of the project however. (That is, according to your screenshots. In reality, _both_ versions appear to have the `og:url` set to `https://www.esourcing.in` right now, which would be wrong to begin with, if you want to share the actual content of the `/uneefy` page.)

Comment: @CBroe In my code I have set the correct canonical url. It works fine in the browser. However the canonical url appears different because Vercel is causing the Facebook crawler to pick up incorrect data. It is the same project (both URLs point to the same project). So the crawler should see the same data for `/uneefy` URL on both domains. I have added a screenshot from my browser to my question.

Comment: on a second look @CBroe was right. The canonical URL was not correct when the crawler fetched the page due to a bug in my code. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. There was a bug in my code

### The bug

I am using a Wrapper component to wrap all my pages. I was setting the `og_url` after `componentDidMount`. I am using a functional component so the `useEffect` hook executes after component mount. Until that happens I set the `og_url` to `https://example.com`.

**However this component mounting never happens when the page is crawled by Facebook.** So you can imagine that the `og:url` property was being set to `https://example.com` for all pages when the Facebook crawler scraped these pages.

```
import Head from "next/head";
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const Wrapper = (props) => {
    const [og_url, setog_url] = useState("")

    useEffect(() => {
        setog_url(window.location.href)
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                ... other meta tags ...

                <meta property="og:url" content={og_url ? og_url : "https://example.com"} />

            </Head>
            {props.children}
        </>
    )
```

### Fix

`og:url` essentially tells Facebook that forget the OG tags on this page and use the OG tags from the page whose url is set to the value of `og:url`. I set the `og:url` to `""` and now the sharing debugger picks up the right OG tags.